# Format attribute to display 8 decimal places in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model, decimal

I want to display my `latitude` and `longitude` to 8 decimal places. However, I am only displaying it to 2 decimal places by default right now. How should I change my Model?

Model:

```
    public class LocationModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Latitude")]
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Longitude")]
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. DataFormatString

```
public class LocationModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Latitude")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:G8}")]
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Longitude")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:G8}")]
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

2. Math

```
public class LocationModel
{
    private decimal _latitude;
    private decimal _longitude;

    [Display(Name = "Latitude")]
    public decimal Latitude
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Round(_latitude, 8);
        }
        set
        {
            this._latitude = value;
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Longitude")]
    public decimal Longitude
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Round(_longitude, 8);
        }
        set
        {
            this._longitude = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On this page of the official Microsoft documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings   There is information on how the DataStringFormat modifiers work